# Leaflet: Geo-Json How to Change Outline Color

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am using Leafleat Maps and have used the following to load geo-json:

- https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json

```
        this.http.get('assets/world.geo.json-master/countries.geo.json').subscribe((json: any) => {
            console.log(json);
            L.geoJSON(json).addTo(map);
        });
```

How can I change the color from blue to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to provide an object as a second parameter to `L.geoJSON` and there define the desired `style` properties, more specifically in your case the `color` property.

```
 L.geoJSON(json, {
    style: {
      // here define your desired color
      color: 'red'
    }
 }).addTo(map);
```

Here is an example to illustrate the above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <script>
    const ukrGeojson = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "UKR",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Ukraine"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              31.785998,
              52.101678
            ],
            [
              32.159412,
              52.061267
            ],
            [
              32.412058,
              52.288695
            ],
            [
              32.715761,
              52.238465
            ],
            [
              33.7527,
              52.335075
            ],
            [
              34.391731,
              51.768882
            ],
            [
              34.141978,
              51.566413
            ],
            [
              34.224816,
              51.255993
            ],
            [
              35.022183,
              51.207572
            ],
            [
              35.377924,
              50.773955
            ],
            [
              35.356116,
              50.577197
            ],
            [
              36.626168,
              50.225591
            ],
            [
              37.39346,
              50.383953
            ],
            [
              38.010631,
              49.915662
            ],
            [
              38.594988,
              49.926462
            ],
            [
              40.069058,
              49.601055
            ],
            [
              40.080789,
              49.30743
            ],
            [
              39.674664,
              48.783818
            ],
            [
              39.895632,
              48.232405
            ],
            [
              39.738278,
              47.898937
            ],
            [
              38.770585,
              47.825608
            ],
            [
              38.255112,
              47.5464
            ],
            [
              38.223538,
              47.10219
            ],
            [
              37.425137,
              47.022221
            ],
            [
              36.759855,
              46.6987
            ],
            [
              35.823685,
              46.645964
            ],
            [
              34.962342,
              46.273197
            ],
            [
              35.020788,
              45.651219
            ],
            [
              35.510009,
              45.409993
            ],
            [
              36.529998,
              45.46999
            ],
            [
              36.334713,
              45.113216
            ],
            [
              35.239999,
              44.939996
            ],
            [
              33.882511,
              44.361479
            ],
            [
              33.326421,
              44.564877
            ],
            [
              33.546924,
              45.034771
            ],
            [
              32.454174,
              45.327466
            ],
            [
              32.630804,
              45.519186
            ],
            [
              33.588162,
              45.851569
            ],
            [
              33.298567,
              46.080598
            ],
            [
              31.74414,
              46.333348
            ],
            [
              31.675307,
              46.706245
            ],
            [
              30.748749,
              46.5831
            ],
            [
              30.377609,
              46.03241
            ],
            [
              29.603289,
              45.293308
            ],
            [
              29.149725,
              45.464925
            ],
            [
              28.679779,
              45.304031
            ],
            [
              28.233554,
              45.488283
            ],
            [
              28.485269,
              45.596907
            ],
            [
              28.659987,
              45.939987
            ],
            [
              28.933717,
              46.25883
            ],
            [
              28.862972,
              46.437889
            ],
            [
              29.072107,
              46.517678
            ],
            [
              29.170654,
              46.379262
            ],
            [
              29.759972,
              46.349988
            ],
            [
              30.024659,
              46.423937
            ],
            [
              29.83821,
              46.525326
            ],
            [
              29.908852,
              46.674361
            ],
            [
              29.559674,
              46.928583
            ],
            [
              29.415135,
              47.346645
            ],
            [
              29.050868,
              47.510227
            ],
            [
              29.122698,
              47.849095
            ],
            [
              28.670891,
              48.118149
            ],
            [
              28.259547,
              48.155562
            ],
            [
              27.522537,
              48.467119
            ],
            [
              26.857824,
              48.368211
            ],
            [
              26.619337,
              48.220726
            ],
            [
              26.19745,
              48.220881
            ],
            [
              25.945941,
              47.987149
            ],
            [
              25.207743,
              47.891056
            ],
            [
              24.866317,
              47.737526
            ],
            [
              24.402056,
              47.981878
            ],
            [
              23.760958,
              47.985598
            ],
            [
              23.142236,
              48.096341
            ],
            [
              22.710531,
              47.882194
            ],
            [
              22.64082,
              48.15024
            ],
            [
              22.085608,
              48.422264
            ],
            [
              22.280842,
              48.825392
            ],
            [
              22.558138,
              49.085738
            ],
            [
              22.776419,
              49.027395
            ],
            [
              22.51845,
              49.476774
            ],
            [
              23.426508,
              50.308506
            ],
            [
              23.922757,
              50.424881
            ],
            [
              24.029986,
              50.705407
            ],
            [
              23.527071,
              51.578454
            ],
            [
              24.005078,
              51.617444
            ],
            [
              24.553106,
              51.888461
            ],
            [
              25.327788,
              51.910656
            ],
            [
              26.337959,
              51.832289
            ],
            [
              27.454066,
              51.592303
            ],
            [
              28.241615,
              51.572227
            ],
            [
              28.617613,
              51.427714
            ],
            [
              28.992835,
              51.602044
            ],
            [
              29.254938,
              51.368234
            ],
            [
              30.157364,
              51.416138
            ],
            [
              30.555117,
              51.319503
            ],
            [
              30.619454,
              51.822806
            ],
            [
              30.927549,
              52.042353
            ],
            [
              31.785998,
              52.101678
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    };

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 3);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.geoJSON(ukrGeojson, {
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }).addTo(mymap);
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```